# Opencart 2.3.0.2 Installation Error Step 3 php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Tags: php, installation, opencart, opencart2.x

Trying to install opencart 2.3.0.2 on a old server. 
All the info fill up should be correct.

Error [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZMiO.png)

> php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

**Infomation Gathered**
I found that this is related to mail issue, and people are able to solve it by changeing to mail instead of SMTP.
However, I face this error during installation of opencart, which does not allow me to change the setting yet.

**Infomation might help**
 - this is a very old server and it is still using PO3 mail protocol

Comment: This may be something you should speak to their own support about as it has nothing to do with programming itself and is out of scope for stack overflow

Comment: Are you able to use the same database settings (obscured in the screenshot) to connect to the database with a remote administration tool like SQLYog / Sequel?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because of at hostname I put http://www.example.com. Everything good when I change it to www.example.com. I reinstall it again and tried this method. It does solve the problem. Anyway, thanks!